# How to kill ediff's buffers on quit?

Tags: ediff

How to kill (C-x k) ediff's (A,B,C) buffers automatically on each `ediff-quit`?

Comment: Did you really mean close the buffers, as opposed to closing the *windows*, i.e. usually going back to a single window showing a single file (but leaving the files open)?

Comment: Yes, I mean kill buffers (C-x k)

Comment: Why do you wish to do this?  Often when I do an ediff I need to continue work on one of the buffers afterwards.

Comment: In my case I'm using ztree-diff to view the diffs and I'm not interested in the files after the diff most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```el
(defun my-kill-ediff-buffers ()
  (kill-buffer ediff-buffer-A)
  (kill-buffer ediff-buffer-B)
  (kill-buffer ediff-buffer-C))

(add-hook 'ediff-quit-hook 'my-kill-ediff-buffers)
```

Note that this will always kill ediff-buffers, even if they weren't opened by ediff e.g. you called `ediff-buffers` with some buffers you had open to start with.

If you want to you could also kill `*ediff-errors*`, `*ediff-diff*`, `*Ediff-Registry*` and `*ediff-fine-diff*` as well, but those generally don't bother me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding an answer because this is the first link that popped up for me on this topic, and this is indeed way simpler.

You can pass a prefix to "q" and it will prompt to kill the ediff buffers.

> C-u q

If you customize `ediff-keep-variants` it will reverse the behaviour: prompt to kill the buffers on exit and if use the prefix will leave them open.

(got this from the ediff manual)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this code (GNU Emacs 25.3.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), following https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17089/18662

As stated in the GNU Emacs Manual regarding *ediff-quit-hook* (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/Hooks.html):

*Keep in mind that hooks executing before ediff-cleanup-mess start in ediff-control-buffer; they should also leave ediff-control-buffer as the current buffer when they finish. Hooks that are executed after ediff-cleanup-mess should expect the current buffer be either buffer A or buffer B.*

So, I kill also the **Ediff Control Panel** buffer. Other ediff buffers may be added too.

```
(setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
(setq ediff-split-window-function 'split-window-horizontally)

(defvar q-ediff-last-windows nil)

(defun q-store-pre-ediff-winconfig ()
    (setq q-ediff-last-windows (current-window-configuration)))

(defun q-restore-pre-ediff-winconfig ()
    (progn
       (set-window-configuration q-ediff-last-windows)
       (ediff-kill-buffer-carefully "*Ediff Control Panel*")))

(add-hook 'ediff-before-setup-hook #'q-store-pre-ediff-winconfig)
(add-hook 'ediff-quit-hook #'q-restore-pre-ediff-winconfig)
```

Comment: +10 for `(setq ediff-split-window-function 'split-window-horizontally)` alone! Was searching for a possibility to always split horizontally in `ztree-diff`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hook:

```el
 (add-hook 'ediff-load-hook
            (lambda ()
              (add-hook 'ediff-before-setup-hook
                        (lambda ()
                          (setq ediff-before-file (buffer-file-name))
                          (setq ediff-saved-window-configuration (current-window-configuration))))
              (let ((restore-window-configuration
                     (lambda ()
                       (set-window-configuration ediff-saved-window-configuration))))
                (add-hook 'ediff-quit-hook restore-window-configuration 'append)
                (add-hook 'ediff-suspend-hook restore-window-configuration 'append))))
```

Comment: It is not recommended to bind `lambda` functions to hooks (and advices). It makes reviewing the hook variables and removing functions from hooks painful.

Comment: This effectively closes the windows, but the question is asking to kill the **buffers**.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using to close the windows:

```
(add-hook 'ediff-after-quit-hook-internal 'winner-undo)
```

Comment: This effectively closes the windows, but the question is asking to kill the **buffers**.