Git difftool on windows causing "Non-hex character used for Unicode escape: s (115)"
I want to use ediff as difftool for git.
I copied the configuration for git from here:
[difftool.ediff]
    cmd = emacs -Q --eval \"(ediff-files \\\"$LOCAL\\\" \\\"$REMOTE\\\")\"
[difftool.ediffclient]
    cmd = emacsclientw --eval \"(ediff-files \\\"$LOCAL\\\" \\\"$REMOTE\\\")\"

Additionally I build myself a difftool named test to evaluate the inputs of $LOCAL and $REMOTE.
[difftool.test]
    cmd = echo $LOCAL && echo $REMOTE

With git difftool --tool=ediff -y origin/main origin/66-branch-to-diff -- source\machine\hmi.c 

Non-hex character used for Unicode escape: s (115)

Same goes for ediffclient as tool.
Now with test as difftool I get:
C:\Users\WHATEVER\AppData\Local\Temp/git-blob-a19916/hmi.c
C:\Users\WHATEVER\AppData\Local\Temp/git-blob-b19916/hmi.c

There is a slash-direction-change in the arguments. I don't know if this may be the reason. I actually have no idea how to proceed and solve this. Googling did not help and testing also brought no results.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?
I am on a windows machine mainly using cmder as command line tool and Git for windows. I also tried it with Git-Bash directly but no difference. Using meld as difftool works just fine (but is to slow and unhandy for me).

I don't know much about Windows, but it does seem plausible that the various escape mechanisms get in each other's way. I would try to debug it by using the emacs command itself on the command line and cutting-and-pasting the actual arguments for $LOCAL and $REMOTE. Then I would (gingerly) modify the quoting until it worked and then transfer it back to .gitconfig and try again -somebody who works with Windows might have a better idea. I would also try with modified paths: change the backslashes to forward slashes and see if that works. That's a debugging suggestion, not a solution.

The error message itself is produced by the Lisp reader when it thinks that it has encountered a Unicode escape of the form \udddd or \Udddddddd where the ds are hex digits, so it almost certainly is getting confused by the \Users part of the pathname and complains about the s not being a hex digit. Maybe doubling up the backslashes in the pathnames might work: C:\\Users\\WHATEVER\\....

To reiterate, these are debugging suggestions, not solutions. Somebody with Windows experience would have to chime in here.

Thanks to the debugging ideas of NickD I came up with the following solution:

Set up a batch file
Modify parameters in batch file
Call emacs with modified parameters

@ECHO OFF
set local=%~1
set remote=%~2


call set local=%%local:\=/%%
call set remote=%%remote:\=/%%


emacs -Q --eval "(ediff-files \"%local%\" \"%remote%\")"


Add batch file as cmd in .gitconfig

[diff]
    tool = test
[difftool.test]
    cmd = C:/Users/chrn/emcl.bat $LOCAL $REMOTE
    trustExitCode = true


So with git difftool I now get a fresh emacs window with ediff preloaded.

To avoid command line problems the following link regarding auto-kill buffers might be usefull ---  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17316/how-to-kill-ediffs-buffers-on-quit
